# LINQ: Get Table details

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQPad and I would like to know schema details of a table.

I know that I do it using SQL:

```
SELECT column_name,* 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '{table_name}'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

How can I do this using LINQ?

Comment: I know that linq pad does it. Perhaps you could Reflect on the linq executable? Resharper has "dotPeek" which is free.

Comment: @Cpfohl: How do I do the reflection?

Comment: I think the below answers are more than sufficient.  To actually look at the source you'd have to download dotPeek from Reflector's website and run it on the exe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to SQL contexts have a `Mapping` property that you can use for this sort of thing. A query like the one you provided might look something like this:

```
from t in context.Mapping.GetTables()
where t.TableName == "[table_name]"
from c in t.RowType.DataMembers
orderby c.Ordinal
select new {columnName = c.Name, columnInfo = c}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380834/how-can-i-walk-the-relationships-between-tables-in-linq/4381910#4381910) for more details.

Comment: I get 'IEnumerable<>(0 items)'

Comment: @inquisitive_one: I'm guessing that's due to your table name. It must be surrounded in brackets, as you see in the given example. So a table called `person_sites` would need to say `"[person_sites]"`.

Comment: I still get the same result.  I'm doing this as a "C# Expression" in LINQPad.

Comment: @inquisitive_one: So am I. Try just doing a `Mapping.GetTables().Select(t => t.TableName)` to see what the actual table names are.

Comment: I now see my mistake.  Thanks.  But how do I get to see the table catalog that my table belongs to?

Comment: @inquisitive_one: I don't understand your question. Are you talking about switching to the right database connection in LINQPad?

Comment: I removed the where clause and it was the answer to a question how to get all table names and their columns in LINQ. one answer two questions FTW!

Answer (score 4):

```
MetaTable t = MyDataContext.Mapping.GetTables().Where(
   i => i.TableName == "TABLENAME").SingleOrDefault();
PropertyInfo[] fields = t.RowType.InheritanceRoot.GetType().GetProperties();
```

'fields' will contain the names and types of the columns.

Comment: I get 'The type of namespace name "MetaTable" could not be found.

Comment: [System.Data.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatable.aspx)

Comment: I still get the same message.  I added "System.Data.Linq.dll" to the query's Additional References.  I'm using "C# Statement(s)" in LINQPad.

Comment: the full namespace for MetaTable is System.Data.Linq.Mapping

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ to SQL, you could try to bring in these views into the model.  If that does not work, you could create a stored procedure that retrieves the info, then LINQ to SQL maps the stored procedure and you execute it as a function.