# Check if column exists in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have database of external program that I want to connect and operate on through LINQ to SQL. My problem is , I want to support wider range of versions of database, so I have to check for columns if they exists.

I tried something like that:

```
      IEnumerable<string> k = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME='{0}' and TABLE_NAME='POSIEDZENIA'", column);
```

And it gives me nothing. k.Count() gives error:

> The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

When I cast it to List by ToList() it gives 0 count.

I'm sure that this column exists in database that datacontext is connected to.

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: are you checking column names or column values >?

Comment: I want to check if column "exists". Actual value doesn't matter.

Comment: It gives result expected :/

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666775/linq-get-table-details

Comment: @OzgurBar there is no enumeration in the link

Comment: @Iceman removed ' quotes and got same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove quotation around parameter (`{0}`).

```
IEnumerable<string> k = db.ExecuteQuery<string>("select column_name from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME={0} and TABLE_NAME='POSIEDZENIA'", column);
```

for more information visit [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx).